# Efficiently encoding a bit array into a limited alphabet

Tags: encoding, compression

This is an efficient encoding problem.

The input is a variable length bit array with a maximum length of 63. For example:

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

`0`s are much more common in this array than `1`s. Lets say `1`s are found about 5% of the time.

My output format is also constrained. I can output a string consisting only of the 36 characters a-z and 0-9. Variable length output is fine.

I want a lossless encoding algorithm that minimizes my average output string length.

A simple lossless encoding would be to assign each of the first 32 letters in my output alphabet to a unique 5 bit sequence, split my input into 5-bit outputs, and output one letter per 5 bits. This gives me an expected string length of:  input array size / 5.

However, this does not exploit either the low probability of `0`s in the input, nor the remaining 4 letters in my alphabet.

Can you suggest a better encoding scheme?

Comment: Perhaps something like a [Tunstall code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunstall_coding) -- code that maps variable number of input bits into a single output alphabet symbol.

Comment: "with a maximum length of 63" -- I assume that means any length between 1 and 63, inclusive? In that case I see a problem with your proposed encoding -- it can only handle lengths that are multiples of 5. The 4 missing codes could be used as "escapes" to signify that only 1-4 bits should be used from the last symbol. (to allow encoding any length, at the cost of 1 extra coded symbol).

Comment: Here's a little script that generates an encoding tree: https://pastebin.com/XLcnyhrJ
The Node/Leaf ids would map to your output alphabet. The last id is reserved for an "escape symbol". The idea is you descend the tree based on input. Once you reach a leaf, you emit its id and start from root again. If you reach the end of input before you reach a leaf, you emit the escape and the ID of the node you're at. Decoding is just a simple table lookup, with the symbol after the escape using second table.

Comment: For probability of 1 being 1/20, it becomes almost like a unary code. The scheme expects the probability of the input symbols to be hardcoded, and the input source to be memory-less. You could improve flexibility by using the first written symbol to represent the probability of zero in steps of 1/36 to make the algorithm more flexible (the decoder could then regenerate a matching tree from that info).

Comment: Yes, any length between 1 and 63 inclusive. The encoding will need to distinguish `[0, 0]` from `[0, 0, 0]`.

The tree description makes sense, but determining the optimal structure of the tree becomes the key.